# Best in position for Blitzball

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I have been playing Blitzball a lot and find it highly addictive...like others seem to also...and noticed that some people are more suited for specific positions compared to others. Obviously based upon stats. This got me thinking about who has the highest overall stats for specific positions in this game. Can anyone tell me who is best for defense, offense, and goalie based upon the specific stats and abilities that would be good for each? Obviously END and SHT for Offense, ATK and BLK for Defense, and CAT for Goalie (also specific abilities for each). If possible can you provide a location where I might find these people also? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the info anyway! Maybe I should have kept Keepa then....oh well he's with the Ronso team in my game now. Yeah I realize the ability difference also, was hoping people answering would too like you did :p I guess I should include it

Comment: Actually, my earlier comment was incorrect.  I have since looked it up, and Keepa has (strangely) the highest `SHT` stat at max level, not `CAT`!

Comment: Actually now that you mention that I remember a friend back in the day showing me his team and Keepa was playing out on forward......yup its a fantasy alright where goalies play forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best stats (ignoring abilities):

SHT @ 99 : Keepa (Aurochs)

PA @ 99 : Vuroja (Kilika Beasts), Linna (Free Player)

SP @ 99 : Brother (Free Player), Nedus (Free Player)

AT @ 73 : Ropp (Free Player)

CAT @ 67 : Nimrook (Al Bhed)

BL @ 82 : Nav (Guado)

EN @ 88 : Basik (Ronso) *not certain this is highest*

HP @ 9999 : Many characters!

Tidus' Stats aren't incredible but his Jecht Shots can make up for them (and the fact that you can't get rid of him and that he is free...)

Compiled from: http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/197344-final-fantasy-x/faqs/19103

Comment: Did you find this somewhere?

Comment: Ah, yes, taken from this source that I should have cited: http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/197344-final-fantasy-x/faqs/19103

Comment: There ya go :p lol

Comment: The intended `GK` has the best `SHT`? That's mental